# I have the Login.Window and Register.Window

Tags: c#

I have the Login.Window and Register.Window coded below.
Now when a user creates an account their have to fill in their username and password.
EXAMPLE Username:John Password:Gold.---- that the information gets stored in the database.
The password is also hashed using compute256. (*6249df4367d0a2e088c8e*)
But when I type the following information into my program Username:John Password:Gold  it says the password doesn’t work, but when I put the hashed password (*6249df4367d0a2e088c8e*)
into the program it works?
I want the actual password and not the hashed password to work when I login to my program.
Any Solutions?

//Register Window

```
public partial class RegisterWindow : Window
{
    public RegisterWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    
      private void Create_Account_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxUsername.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxPassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all fields.");
        }
        else if (TextBoxPassword.Text != TextConfirmPassword.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match.");
        }
        else
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("UserAdd", sqlCon))
                {
                    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", TextBoxUsername.Text.Trim());

                    // Hash the password before storing it in the database
                    string hashedPassword = HashPassword(TextBoxPassword.Text);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", hashedPassword);

                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Registration is successful.");
        }
        Clear();
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        TextBoxUsername.Text = "";
        TextBoxPassword.Text = "";
    }

    // Hash the password using a secure hashing algorithm (e.g., bcrypt)
    private string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        using (var sha256 = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            var hashBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            return BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

}

//Login Window

private async void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

```
            SqlDataAdapter sqa = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count (*) From Login where Username = '" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "' and Password = '" + TextBoxPassword.Text + "'", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sqa.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.Hide();
                MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                main.Show();
            }
            else
             {

                 MessageBox.Show( "You have inputted incorrect details!");

             }


                //Spinner.IsLoading = true;
                TextBlockResponse.Text = "";
               
                StudyTrackerContext context = new StudyTrackerContext();
                var user = await (context.users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.username == TextBoxUsername.Text && b.password == TextBoxPassword.Text));

                if (user == null)
                {
                    TextBlockResponse.Text = "You have inputted incorrect details!";
                }
                 else
                {
                    TextBlockResponse.Text = "Success! Welcome " + user.username;
                }
                 Spinner.IsLoading = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYxuh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You say yourself that the password value stored in the database is hashed. How, then, could it be useful to compare the actual password the user enters at login to that value? Of course they're not going to be the same. The fact that entering the hashed value works should have been a clue: you have to compare the hashed value to the hashed value.

When the user logs in, you hash the password they provided in exactly the same way as you did when they registered, then you compare the new hashed value to the value stored in the database. If they matched then the two hashes were generated from the same initial value, i.e. the password entered at login is the same as the password entered at registration.